# median stack mode is blurring my stars

Tags: night, stars, image-stacking, sky

i am trying to reduce noise with median stack filter but all the stars are smeared/blurred.
Gear nikon D7100, Samyang 10mm, tripod, PS CC

Comment: Have you turned on automatic realignment to account for the apparent motion of the stars in the sky between each exposure?

Comment: Nope i did not. Where can i find this setting?

Comment: What software are you using to stack the images? That's were you would do alignment.

Answer (score 3):

The Earth rotates, which causes the stars to appear to move, which would be expected to cause them to appear blurry when the images are stacked. Consider using a program, such as `align_image_stack` to align the stars before stacking.

See [Cannot align images with align_image_stack](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83178/75526).